# Python super() - should be working but isn't?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

As far as I can tell, and everything I've been finding online, this should work (but it doesn't, which is why I'm asking here ;) )

```
class Tigon(Crossbreeds, Predator, Lion):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def printSize(self):
        print("Huge")
```

Both "Crossbreeds" and "Predator" inherit from "Mammal", and "Lion" inherits from Predator.  The compilation of those works fine.  I'm working on Python 3.2, though I did also try the earlier:

Edit:  Sorry, part of my post didn't come through for some reason.

I also tried:

```
class Tigon(Crossbreeds, Predator, Lion):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Tigon, self).__init__()
    def printSize(self):
        print("Huge")
```

and both of them gave me:

```
class Tigon(Crossbreeds, Predator, Lion):
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases Predator, Mammal, Lion
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to write what exactly doesn't work so we can help. Also `super()` normally takes arguments: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super

Comment: Sorry, part of the post didn't come through.  Edited now

Comment: @viraptor: super() in python 3 does not need arguments (though it can still take them) and it might make sense to specify them if it does not work without.

Comment: ah - didn't spot the python3 part, fair enough then :)

Comment: Check out the most comprehensive guide to super: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236275

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: Don't inherit the same base class directly and indirectly, but inheriting directly *after* indirectly should work. So don't inherit `Predator` or inherit it *after* `Lion`.

Well, the [C3 MRO](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) seems to not be able to find any order consistent with all constraints. The constraints are that:

- each class must come before it's base classes
- and the base classes must come in the order they are listed.

You inherit `Crossbreeds`, `Predator` and `Lion` in that order, so their methods must be called in that order. But since `Lion` inherits `Predator`, it's methods must be called before those of `Predator`. Which is not possible, therefore it says it can't create consistent method resolution order.

Comment: Thanks! I get it.   So that means that `(Crossbreeds, Lion, Predator)` should work, right? 
That gives me another question - using that phrasing, what should I do if I want `Tigon` to inherit a method that is defined differently in `Lion` and `Predators`, and I want `Tigon` to take it from `Predators`?

Answer (score 0):

<del>Should be `super().__init__(self)`.</del>

Edited:
My apologize, you should put `Lion` front:

```
class Tigon(Lion, Predator, Crossbreeds):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Comment: @Jan - can you tell what the problem is?

Comment: The statement is not the problem (and was correct). The inheritance is.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood the inheritance model you described, this is how you should define the `Tigon` class:

```
class Mammal(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Mammal, self).__init__()

class Crossbreeds(Mammal):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Crossbreeds, self).__init__()

class Predator(Mammal):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Predator, self).__init__()

class Lion(Predator):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Lion, self).__init__()

class Tigon(Lion, Crossbreeds, Predator):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Tigon, self).__init__()

t = Tigon()
```

this alternative is equivalent, since Lion is a Predator:

```
class Tigon(Lion, Crossbreeds):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Tigon, self).__init__()
```

Now here's a quick rule for this. Each class' constructor is called after base classes, but they must appear in the **reverse** order in the class definition. Also, classes that override methods defined in their parent class(es) must appear first in class definitions - this means that if you wanted to override a method of Predator in Lion, Lion should appear before Predator in the definition. The longer explanation for this is in [Jan Hudec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057540/python-super-should-be-working-but-isnt/6057743#6057743).

Comment: See [Jan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057540/python-super-should-be-working-but-isnt/6057743#6057743) for a description of why